# Google Maps API directions recalculate on drag

Tags: google-maps-api-3, map-directions

Thank you for your time.

**Brief:**

- Google Maps API V3 project
- Click on map to place markers
- Directions Service calculates route between two sequential points

**Goal:**

Recalculate the route when one of the markers is dragged.

**Progress:**

So far I have assembled this page: http://test.bluecactus.ro/gmaps.html. I have commented most of the code.

**Problem:**

Page works OK for the first drag. When I drag a second marker or drag the first one again, the polylines are no longer 'regenerated' the way they should be (delete incoming and outgoing, calculate from new position, plot on map).

For multiple drags on same marker some polylines that should be deleted will be left on the map. On dragging a second marker, the wrong polylines are deleted.

This lead me to believe something is wrong with identifying of the dragged marker's position in the array which holds all of the markers; *function below*. I have redone the 'math' several times - on paper it seems OK. I have tried putting everything outside the *for* loop and using the loop just to identify the position in a global variable. None of them worked.

**http://test.bluecactus.ro/gmaps.html**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) { //ondrag
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if(gmarkers[i].getPosition() == marker.getPosition()) { //find out array position of current marker
        console.log("i = " + i);
        //hide incoming and outgoing polylines; polylines index offset by -1 (n markers => n-1 polylines)
        gpolys[i-1].setMap(null);
        gpolys[i].setMap(null);
        drawPath(gmarkers[i-1].getPosition(), marker.getPosition()); //calculate route between moved marker and previous point
        drawPath(marker.getPosition(), gmarkers[i+1].getPosition()); //calculate route between moved marker and next point
        //overwrite initial polylines; drawPath function automatically adds new polylines to end of gpolys array
        gpolys[i-1] = gpolys[gpolys.length-2]; 
        console.log(gpolys);
        gpolys[i] = gpolys[gpolys.length-1];
        console.log(gpolys);
        //delete last 2 elements from gpolys
        gpolys.pop(); 
        console.log(gpolys);
        gpolys.pop();
        console.log(gpolys);
      }
    }
});
```

**Notes**:

- First and last marker will not work, they are not dealt with for the moment.
- I have found somewhat of a workaround: on drag recalculate the whole route - take all markers in the array and plot between i & i+1; however this works only for smaller routes and without dragging to fast - otherwise to OVER_QUERY_LIMIT will be hit. Could be resolved with a delay between calls, but seems odd to recalculate everything everytime just for one point.

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but can't grasp it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is in the "Problem" section. Sorry, I'll make it more clear: What am I doing wrong in the dragend function (or possibly somewhere else), as the poylines are not being redrawn as they should be?

Comment: I thought I might be going about this the wrong way, so I've redone the map using the standard DirectionService (call the service, save the generated polyline in an array and overlay it on the map). However, I still have problems when dragging, because it reverts back to the original directions: http://test.bluecactus.ro/gmaps2.html. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement dragging directions yourself, it's already part of the JavaScript API v3 since 2010. You can have markers on waypoints, but any point in the route is draggable.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DraggableDirections